# Why does Spanish locale sort order differ between CentOs 6.9 and Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: locale, ubuntu-18.04, centos6

Does anybody have a good explanation why Spanish locale sort order differs between CentOs 6.9 and Ubuntu 18.04:

On CentOS release 6.9:

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=es_ES.utf8
$ echo "niño ninja ninus" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
ninja
niño
ninus
```

And on Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=es_ES.utf8
$ echo "niño ninja ninus" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
ninja
ninus
niño
```

So in Centos6.9 "niño" is sorted before "ninus" while Ubuntu 18.04 reverses that order.

Comment: Can not reproduce.

Comment: Was due to a difference in underlying operating systems (experiments were run in different containers)

Comment: The original question was why the sort order differs between Py2 and Py3.  I completely rephrased the question to reflect that the difference comes from the underlying OS.

Comment: It looks like CentOS uses an accent-insensitive collation while Ubuntu is accent-sensitive.

Comment: Shouldn't the locale setting determine whether the collation is accent sensitive or not?

Comment: According to someone who knows Spanish, "ñ" should be sorted after "n" and before "o" as a completely independent letter.  So the Ubuntu 18.04 locale's sort order is the correct one.  CentOS6.9 locale treats "ñ" basically as an "n" which seems incorrect.